# Switch between SSO and individual user account authentication schemas in single ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on

I have been tasked with switching our current system from using an individual account authentication schema to using SSO or individual accounts based on whether or not the user's organization has enabled SSO (indicated by a boolean stored in the organization/domain data in SQL server).

As far as I understand it, in Program.cs, when you add the OpenIdConnectDefaults authentication schema that automatically causes the redirect to the specified Azure AD instance when the user navigates to the page, which is not what we want to happen for users whose organizations are set up for individual user accounts.

I tried looking through the Microsoft docs for a way to control when this redirect happens or for a way to conditionally set which authentication schema is used, but I wasn't having luck finding anything that particularly pertained to this issue. I also tried using third party libraries such as [ITFoxTec.Identity.Saml2](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2) for help in being able to control when that redirect happens, but I found the documentation to be lacking and their sample Web App project didn't work. I'd prefer to use a solution that doesn't have to rely on third party code for dependency sake, regardless.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: this requires writing your own authentication middleware. If you are using EF, you will need to store this middleware after EF so that you can query the database in your custom auth middleware to check for the company preference, and conditionally perform authentication.

Comment: I will recommend first getting SSO to work, and then also get individual accounts authentication to work on a separate branch as well, then dissect what exactly is happening in those middlewares and copy paste the related code into your new custom middleware which will conditionally perform whichever method of authentication is to be performed.

Comment: it is not likely for anyone to be able to give you the code for this middleware. you have a difficult task at hand that requires deep knowledge of authentication and authorization. if I were in your shoes, I would try and convince the company that simply developing your own OAuth server for OAuth and OIDC (with a library like IdentityServer4, for example) is a healthier solution, which would avoid any additional 3rd party service costs (Azure AD) and would achieve SSO just the same.

Comment: to me it seems that what you would get after such a work is simply not worth it, and you might as well have developed your own OAuth server at that point, but I understand you have to do what you are told to do. I hope I was able to atleast give you some general ideas.

Comment: this might help https://www.developerload.com/problems-using-microsoft-identity-web-app-and-microsoftaspnetcoreidentity-in-the-same-web-project